# IBM Sales Center Client

Tags: eclipse-plugin, websphere-commerce

I want to run IBM Sales Center Client on eclipse. I read the IBM Infocenter document. But I can not configure it. I searched for plugins, but dint find any. Please guide me, How to run Sales Center Client on eclipse. Sales Center Developer App is already installed on my machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to find the update site jar files within the installation directory/CD and add them into your version of eclipse. The jar/zip files are usually in a folder marked **updates** or **update_sites**.

Once found, follow these instructions to import and add them into your eclipse.

> Select File > Application > Install
>   Select Search for new features to install and click Next.
>
> Click on Add Folder Location and browse to the folder
>   drive:\DRE\updates\client and click OK.
>   Note: By default, drive is your DVD drive containing the IBM Sales
>   Center DVD.
>
> In the Name field, provide a value (for example, DRE) and click OK.
>
> Click on Add Folder Location and browse to the folder drive:\SPRFix
>   and click OK.
>   Note: By default, drive is your DVD drive containing the IBM Sales
>   Center DVD.
>
> In the Name field, provide a value (for example, SPRFix) and click OK.
>
> Click on Add Folder Location and browse to the folder drive:\ISCWC and
>   click OK. Notes:
>
> By default, drive is your DVD drive containing the IBM Sales Center
>   DVD.
>
> If you have moved the installation packages into a ZIP/JAR file, or on
>   to a remote Web server, you can select the Add Zip/Jar Location or Add
>   Remote Location options.
>
> In the Name field, provide a value (for example, ISCWC) and click OK.
>
> Make sure all of the update sites you added are selected and click
>   Finish.
>
> On the Search Results panel, select Core JVM Feature –J2SE and UI
>   Widgets under the Runtime Components and select everything under the
>   IBM Sales Center for WebSphere Commerce. Click Next.
>
> Read and accept the license agreement and click Next.
>
> Review the summary and click Finish to start installing. Wait for the
>
> Provisioning Operation to finish.
>
> Once the provisioning is finished, click Restart Now to restart Lotus
>   Expeditor.
>
> To verify that Sales Center is installed, click the Open button and
>   you should see any WebSphere Commerce stores you have created in the
>   list.